# Where Query in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

if parameter @ABC is not null then add in where query

```
@XYZ bigint,
@ABC tinyint=null

select * from WTY where 
xyz=@XYZ and ABC=@ABC
```

---as when @ABC is null it didn't get any result
-- require condion for ABC checks only when @ABC is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
@XYZ bigint,
@ABC tinyint=null

select * from WTY where 
xyz=@XYZ and ABC=@ABC OR @ABC is NULL
```

or you can also use

```
select * from WTY where 
xyz=@XYZ and ABC=isnull(@ABC , ABC)
```